# Elasticsearch cannot parse date using custom format

Tags: parsing, date, elasticsearch, jodatime, datetime-format

According to the documentation (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html), it should be possible to parse dates using a Joda time compatible date pattern.

My data contains dates like this: "2015-02-09 02:10:05,245".

These can be parsed with Joda time using the following pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS".

However, when I tell my index to use this pattern to parse dates, loading data into Elasticsearch fails with the following error:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [mydate]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:416)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeValue(ObjectMapper.java:709)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:500)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:542)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:491)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareCreate(InternalIndexShard.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardIndexOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:444)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:512)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse date field [2015-02-09 02:10:05,245], tried both date format [dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number with locale []
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DateFieldMapper.parseStringValue(DateFieldMapper.java:621)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DateFieldMapper.innerParseCreateField(DateFieldMapper.java:549)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.NumberFieldMapper.parseCreateField(NumberFieldMapper.java:235)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:406)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2015-02-09 02:10:05,245" is malformed at " 02:10:05,245"
    at org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:754)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DateFieldMapper.parseStringValue(DateFieldMapper.java:615)
    ... 15 more
```

In the index template, 'mydate' is specified like this:

```
{
  "template": "te*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_" : {
      "properties": {
        "mydate": {
          "index": "analyzed",
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That should do it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me on ES 1.4.4

```
PUT hilden1

PUT hilden1/type1/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "dt": {"type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"}
  }
}

POST hilden1/type1
{
  "dt": "2015-02-09 02:10:05,245"
}

GET hilden1/type1/_search
```

Comment: I don't really know why, but I've got things working now. I noticed you have explicitly created a type 'type1', where I rely on _default_. I changed my index, replaced _default_ with type1 and told logstash to use  type1 as index_type. Now it just works.

Comment: You will most likely have lots of types within an index so its good practice to call them out

Comment: Help me to find my error. My mappings had the wrong `type` stated, so that's why elasticsearch could not map the specified date format. Using the correct name of the type solved the problem for me.